# The right way to copy __proto__ value from one object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have this micro-library in the works that is meant to be like a lightweight jQuery (let's call it kQuery).

Here is some abridged code:

```
(function(_){

    var dom_obj,
        ret_obj;

    var kQuery = function(selector, context, undefined){
        dom_obj = new Dom(selector, context, undefined);
        ret_obj = dom_obj.core;
        ret_obj.__proto__ = dom_obj.constructor.prototype;

        return ret_obj;
    };

    function Dom(selector, context, undefined)
    {
        var el;
        el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        this.core = [];
        var payload = (_.count(el) === 1) ? el[0] : el;
        this.core.push(payload);
        this.core.context = window.document;
        this.core.selector = selector;
    }

    Dom.prototype.each = function(callback){
        //my each method code
    };

    Dom.prototype.find = function(selector) 
    {
        //my find method code
    };

    Dom.prototype.addClass = function(class_name) 
    {
        //my addClass method code
    };

    //assign to window object
    window.kQuery = kQuery;

    //assign to $ namespace if it is undefined
    window.$ = window.$ || window.kQuery;

})(_);
```

Note: `_` is not underscorejs, just something very similar.

The above code works [and by works, I mean that it creates an array-like object very similar to an object created by jQuery e.g. `$('#element_id')`)], but I've read that using `__proto__` this way is probably not the best (anti-pattern and not cross-browser).

Is there another way to rewrite `ret_obj.__proto__ = dom_obj.constructor.prototype;` in a cross-browser [ie8 baseline] way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this:

```
(function(_){
    if (!Object.create)
    {
        Object.create = function(o, properties)
        {
            if (typeof o !== 'object' && typeof o !== 'function')
            {
                throw new TypeError('Object prototype may only be an Object: ' + o);
            }
            else if (o === null)
            {
                throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support 'null' as the first argument.");
            }

            /*jshint -W116 */
            if (typeof properties != 'undefined')
            {
                throw new Error("This browser's implementation of Object.create is a shim and doesn't support a second argument.");
            }
            /*jshint +W116 */

            function F() {}
            F.prototype = o;
            return new F();
        };
    }

    function merge( first, second ) 
    {
        var len = +second.length,
            j = 0,
            i = first.length;

        while ( j < len ) {
            first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
        }

        // Support: IE<9
        // Workaround casting of .length to NaN on otherwise arraylike objects (e.g., NodeLists)
        if ( len !== len ) {
            while ( second[j] !== undefined ) {
                first[ i++ ] = second[ j++ ];
            }
        }

        first.length = i;

        return first;
    }

    var init_dom_obj,
        dom_obj;

    var kQuery = function(selector, context, undefined){
        init_dom_obj = new initDom(selector, context, undefined);
        dom_obj = new Dom();
        dom_obj = merge(dom_obj, init_dom_obj.core);

        dom_obj.context = init_dom_obj.context;
        dom_obj.selector = init_dom_obj.selector;

        return dom_obj;
    };

    function Dom(){}
    Dom.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

    function initDom(selector, context, undefined)
    {
        var el;
        el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        this.core = [];
        var payload = (_.count(el) === 1) ? el[0] : el;
        this.core.push(payload);
        this.context = window.document;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    Dom.prototype.each = function(callback){
        //my each method code
    };

    Dom.prototype.find = function(selector) 
    {
        //my find method code
    };

    Dom.prototype.addClass = function(class_name) 
    {
        //my addClass method code
    };

    //assign to window object
    window.kQuery = kQuery;

    //assign to $ namespace if it is undefined
    window.$ = window.$ || window.kQuery;

})(_);
```

Since it's problematic to change `__proto__` [the way I was trying to do it initially] once the object is already created, I figured it would be better to do things in a roundabout way by:

1. Moving the initial constructor to a distinct function/object space ['initDom'] and using it to host the selected object
2. Creating the main object [`Dom`] with an array-like structure and all required methods from the get-go
3. Merging the selected object [`init_dom_obj.core`] with our main `Dom` object (doable since they are both array-like)
4. Reinstating the lost object properties [which were lost on account of the merge operation] manually

Hope this helps if you're building a micro-library, or something like it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Object.create` in this instance.

```
ret_obj = Object.create(dom_obj.constructor.prototype, dom_obj.core)
```

Comment: Unfortunately IE8 doesn't have `Object.create`.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object:`. I guess it's because `dom_obj.core` is an array.

Comment: @joews If it doesn't support ES5, just create a constructor function with the prototype set to `dom_obj.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill Why are you changing a proto of an Array then? That's a huge code smell!

Comment: @ObinwanneHill which part in particular? Basically, how do you want it work? I mentioned that it's code-smell to re-write the prototype of an Array because arrays are meant to work as a list. If you want to perform specific actions on them, then you could use a function but try to avoid re-writing an array's prototype to avoid unnecessary side effects. Rewriting it's proto means that you can't use any of the built-in Array methods (which means it's not an array anymore)

Comment: @Bwaxxlo I don't need it to be an array, I just need it to look like one (if you inspect a jQuery object in Chrome Dev Tools you'll see what I mean) i.e. square brackets, but key-value pairs. The only functions I need are the ones in `dom_obj`, which is why I ported the constructor to `__proto__`. I know my initial solution is not the best and that's why I'm looking for a better way to write this.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill I guess in that case, you can use `Object.setPrototypeOf`

Comment: @ObinwanneHill Just realised the IE8 angle in the original question. I guess what you posted it good enough :(

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see that you could do this is in IE 8 to create a new Object (using the `new` operator) and then assigning the properties of `dom_obj.core` onto it in the constructor:

```
var kQuery = function(selector, context, undefined){
    dom_obj = new Dom(selector, context, undefined);

    function ret_obj_proto (domob) {
        for(var item in domob) {
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(domob, item)) { // Check if it is an own property, IE 8 style
                this[item] = domob[item];
            }
        }
    };

    ret_obj_proto.prototype = dom_obj.constructor.prototype;
    ret_obj = new ret_obj_proto(dom_obj);

    return ret_obj;
};
```

I am very curious if there is a better solution to this though.

Comment: Thanks. The result of this is not really what I want; I want it to be the same as JQuery, and my initial solution does it except the `__proto__`. I've been looking at JQuery's code, but can't quite figure out how they got it to work

Comment: What is wrong with the result (specifics would help)?
Also, why *do* you need to create a separate return object from `Dom`? Can't you just return the `dom_obj`?
PS: JQuery just returns a new instance of an internal function called `init`: `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );` there is no `__proto__` involved.

Comment: If you use Chrome Dev Tools you might get a clearer picture of what I'm referring to. If you inspect the object using JQuery e.g. `console.log($('#some_element'));` you'll notice the array-like structure is different from an object-like structure. The `dom_obj` has what I need, but I'd like to promote the contents of `dom_obj.core` to the primary object level (instead of having it as a property) and maintain an array-like structure, without losing the value in `__proto__`...is this possible?

Comment: jQuery returns a regular Object with numbers as indices for their elements. `$('.topbar-icon');` returns the following object for the DOM references: `Object { 0: <a.topbar-icon.icon-site-switcher.yes-hover.js-site-switcher-button.js-gps-track>, 1: <a.topbar-icon.icon-inbox.yes-hover.js-inbox-button>, 2: <a.topbar-icon.icon-achievements.yes-hover.js-achievements-button>, length: 3, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → 33808753, selector: ".topbar-icon" }` You don't need `__proto__` to create an Object like that. In your Dom constructor, instead of assigning it to `this.core`...

Comment: ... just assign it to numeric indices of `this` (e.g. `this[0] = payload[0]`). If you use a loop, you can do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip with `this[0]`. A few weeks ago that would have been enough for me. However, if you look at that JQuery object in Chrome Dev Tools, you may notice that it is within square brackets i.e. array-like with `length` property; this comes in handy when doing a number of operations. I seem to have put together a more convoluted workaround and will post the code as soon as I can lay it out in line with my initial question.

Comment: Yes, Chrome Dev Tools, for whatever reason, decided to show jQuery Objects in square brackets (that has nothing to do with the Object type, that is just Chrome's way of displaying Objects created by jQuery). This is a regular Object (have a look at it in Firefox or IE Dev Tools). Or run `console.dir($('div'));` in Chrome, then you will see that there are other properties as well.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools seems to make some distinction for array [or array-like] objects and uses square brackets, which is a good thing if you ask me. I'll post the solution I found soon

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an ES6 environment, use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(ret_obj, dom_obj.constructor.prototype)
```

[Compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.setPrototypeOf)

Comment: I've just noticed the IE8 part. I'll leave this answer here in case it helps somebody else.